# Retrieving values from 2 different tables with Django's QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models

For the following models:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Toppping)
```

My data looks like the following:

Pizza and Topping tables joined:

```
ID  NAME        TOPPINGS
------------------------------------
1   deluxe      topping_1, topping_2
2   deluxe      topping_3, topping_4
3   hawaiian    topping_1
```

I want to get the pizza id along with their corresponding toppings for all pizza named `deluxe`.  My expected result is:

```
1   topping_1
1   topping_2
2   topping_3
2   topping_4
```

The junction table is:

```
pizza_toppings
--------------
id    
pizza_id    
topping_id
```

Here's the SQL equivalent of what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT p.id, t.name
FROM pizza_toppings AS pt
INNER JOIN pizza AS p ON p.id = pt.pizza_id
INNER JOIN topping AS t ON t.id = pt.topping_id
WHERE p.name = 'deluxe'
```

Any ideas on what the corresponding Django Queryset looks like?  I also want to sort the resulting toppings by name if the above is not challenging enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a clean solution to this, since you want data from two different models. Depending on your data structure you might want to use select_related to avoid hitting the database for all the toppings. Going for your desired result, I would do:

```
result = []
pizzas = Pizza.objects.select_related().filter(name='deluxe')
for pizza in pizzas:
    for toppings in pizza.toppings.all():
        result.append((pizza.pk, topping.name))
```

This would generate:

```
[
    (1, topping_1),
    (1, topping_2),
    (2, topping_3),
    (2, topping_4),
]
```

Now there are different ways to setup the data, using lists, tuples and dictionaries, but I think you get the idea of how you could do it.

Comment: Great, that along with question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary helped solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get a pizza when you have a topping from the model above. You could do

```
pizzas = topping.pizza_set.all()
```

for all pizzas with a topping or probably (in case the topping exists on only one pizza with the name "deluxe")

```
pizza = topping.pizza_set.get(name="deluxe")
```

once you have a topping. Or, you could store the Pizza and the Topping in a list of tuples or a dictionary (if there are no duplicate toppings):

```
toppings = {}
pizzas = Pizza.objects.filter(name="deluxe")
for pizza in pizzas:
    for topping in pizza.toppings.all():
        toppings[topping.name] = pizza.name
sorted_toppings = toppings.keys()
sorted_toppings.sort()
```

Then you can fetch the pizza for a topping with the dictionary.

Comment: I have that solution too, I was wondering if there's a more elegant one because I also want to sort my toppings by name.

Comment: There are likely more elegant ways to achieve this. Sorting isn't an issue though:
toppings = list(toppings)
toppings.sort()

Comment: The toppings are sorted by pizza with this solution, my goal is to get a global sorted list of all the toppings for the deluxe pizza.

Comment: If you have all the toppings for the deluxe pizza in a list as above and sort this list, then it is a 'global' sorted list of all the toppings. If you're up for something 'more elegant' you could get the toppings of each matching pizza in a set and then merge this set with the total set. Doesn't seem to pay off for pizza & toppings though. Will go to bed now and check back tomorrow.

Comment: How do I then get the corresponding pizza id for each of those toppings?

Comment: I think I finally understood what you wanted. Let me know if there's something else I didn't get right in the first place :)